# Get string from JSON like PHP in Java

Tags: java, json, org.json

I was wondering if there is a way to get a string from JSON in Java like there is in PHP:

```
<?php
$json = @file_get_contents('example');

$decoded_json = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded_json->{"something"} ;
?>
```

I have currently tried:

```
String input = "[{"minecraft.net":"green"},{"session.minecraft.net":"green"},{"account.mojang.com":"green"},{"auth.mojang.com":"green"},{"skins.minecraft.net":"green"},{"authserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"sessionserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"api.mojang.com":"green"},{"textures.minecraft.net":"green"}]";
String wanted = "minecraft.net";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(input);
String out = json.getString(wanted);
System.out.println(out);
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: Seems like the quotes used within the json string should be escaped.

Comment: Ooopsy, gave the wrong code. The right one has them escaped.

Answer (score 4):

It's because your String is not a valid JSON object but a valid JSON array which contains objects, try to use JSONArray instead then you can query around this array for your desired object

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add \" when a double quote is inside another double quote